# New ceiling fan with remote wiring

Tags: wiring, ceiling-fan

Old ceiling fan with light, no remote. Wires at ceiling are red (power), black (power), white (neutral) & gnd. Old fan had one white, two blue and gnd. All wires were connected. Black and red were each connected to one each blue. Two wall switches at different locations send power to fixture.

New ceiling fan with light and remote control. New fixture only has one white, one black and gnd.

Do I connect both black (house) & red (house) to black (fan). Or do I cap off red and only do black to black?

Comment: What make and model is your new fan?

Comment: Did you previously have one switch that controlled the fan and a separate switch that controlled the light? Do you want to have that type of setup or do you want to exclusively use the remote? Or do you want to use the remote for one part (e.g., fan speed) and a switch for the lights?

Comment: Thank you for responding, but I figured it out and all is well.